# SymmetricDS: How to filter row using sql statement in router?

Tags: symmetricds

I have a condition such as `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.Status = 'A' and table1.Description like '%valid%'`
How could I put this statement inside the router so that I know which row should send to target ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the subselect router which allows for custom queries definition:

```
select node_id
from   sym_node
where  0 < (
  select count(*)
  FROM   table1 
  WHERE  table1.Status = 'A' 
  and    table1.Description like '%valid%'
  and    table1.id = :id
);
```

Comment: what is :id ? I only have an identity column which may not be the same for source and target.

Comment: replace the 'id' with the name of your primary key column

Comment: Except id which is an identity column, I try use few columns to distinct unique data, like description to distinct each row. But it failed to sync